# Update parent state variable from child React Reactive Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to explore `react` library with `next` framework. Since I am an `angular` developer, I like to reuse some of my `reactive-form` to my new application. I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-reactive-form) library since it has almost the same implementation of `reactive-form`.

Now, I am using `state` variable on my parent form; however, whenever I try to update the value from child (which is the reactive form). I cannot accomplish it.

Here's my simple code to replicate this.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FieldGroup, FieldControl } from "react-reactive-form";

export default function App() {
  const [isRegistered, setIsRegistered] = useState(false);

  async function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsRegistered(state => !state);
    console.log(isRegistered);
    //await function call .....
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <FieldGroup
        control={form}
        render={({ get, invalid }) => (
          <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
            <FieldControl
              name="email"
              render={TextInput}
              meta={{ label: "Email" }}
            />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            <p>{isRegistered.toString()}</p>
            {isRegistered ? <span>Registered Successfully</span> : null}
          </form>
        )}
      />
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

Just to keep it short, the `form` and `TextInput` is just a model and an element.

As you can see., I am updating my state variable on the `submitForm` function by putting it as an `onSubmit` function of my form; however, I am able to trigger the `submitForm` whenever I am trying to submit, but the `state variable` value doesn't change.

The thing is, when I try to call the `submitForm` function outside the `child` (FieldGroup), I am able to update the value.

I created a [sample app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5jzqv3?file=src/App.js) so you can check as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to set `strict` prop to `false` for `FieldGroup`, like described here: https://github.com/bietkul/react-reactive-form/blob/master/docs/api/FieldGroup.md

> `strict: boolean;`
>
> Default value: true
>
> If true then it'll only re-render the component only when any change happens in the form group control irrespective of the parent component(state and props) changes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this library, but to me it just looks like the FormGroup is not re-render, because none of it's props are being changed.

The documentation says that passing `strict={false}` to the `<FieldGroup />` component should allow it to re-render when the parent component updates as well. In your given example (thanks for making an example) that also does the trick.